# Wordpress - Add custom menu to a page

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to create a new menu, and if possibe place the menu on the page via the page builder, so if possible put a slug in between two divs, and it displays on the page in the left panel.

Comment: Yes it's possible in WordPress adding custom menu to a page.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to review the [help on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), in particular [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). and this [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to see what sort of question you can ask here and what you need to include so you get the help you need.